# Shiny server illegal option error

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have shiny running on a mac. These apps have previously been working. I'm getting the following error when I try to access any of them

The application failed to start.

The application exited during initialization.

```
su: illegal option -- p
usage: su [-] [-flm] [login [args]]
```

This is also all that is in the log. Any ideas on what is going on here? I know shiny server is not intended for mac which is why we are transitioning to a linux server, but in the meantime I need these apps which were previously working to continue working.

Comment: what full command are you using when trying to launch the shiny server?

Comment: @mysteRious I'm using sudo shiny-server. I'm not terribly familiar with mac commands. This launches shiny server with an index of the apps but then each one of them has this error.

Comment: sudo just lets you run a process as root -- have you already installed it from a .deb installer?

Comment: are you using "sudo systemctl start shiny-server" to start the app? I suggest also providing details about the Linux distribution you're working with (RHEL7, Ubuntu, etc.).

Comment: @mysteRious yes I installed it, these apps were previously running.

Comment: @DaleKube yes I am using that on our linux server. The problem I'm having is running shiny server on a Mac, the original apps were created on a mac and I need to keep them running as I recreate and simplify them on a suse linux server. Currently a version of the app with no data in it is properly functioning on my linux server.